# Specular gets too bright when viewing sphere from behind

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I've been trying to render a good planet material in Blender but I've noticed while my planet looks great from the front, the oceans look far too bright when viewed from a back angle.

[image]
[image]

Compare this to Celestia or SpaceEngine, where the oceans still look blue from this angle:

[image]
[image]

I thought maybe it was my node setup since I'm combining a glossy BDSF and a regular principled BDSF for the ocean, but trying the same experiment with a regular principled BDSF and no special settings resulted in the same problem:

[image]
[image]

Do I need to be using a different light source than a Sun? Is there a setting in the Rendering tab I need to adjust? I've tried tweaking the material and the light source settings to no avail.